# How can I check the progress of my Facebook iOS upload?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK and using the Graph API to upload videos to Facebook.

The uploading is working perfectly fine, but can I keep track of the progress of the upload so I can reflect the progress in a progress bar.

Comment: Did you find a way to check the progress in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question but what you're trying to do is possible with latest Facebook iOS SDK v3.9. (27 Oct 2013)

Essentially, FBRequestConnection exposes a property urlRequest (NSMutableURLRequest) that you can use to send out the data any other third party networking frameworks or even the ones Apple provided.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequestConnection#urlRequest

Here's an example how I get progress callbacks using AFNetworking 1.x.

## Prepare Request Body

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"video.mov": videoData,
                              @"title": @"Upload Title",
                              @"description": @"Upload Description" };
```

## Create FBRequest

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" 
                                          parameters:parameters
                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

## Generate FBRequestConnection (Cancel & Extract URLRequest)

```
FBRequestConnection *requestConnection = [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}];
[requestConnection cancel];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = requestConnection.urlRequest;
```

## Use AFNetworking HTTPRequestOperation

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  // Do your success callback.
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  // Do your failure callback.
}];
```

## Set Progress Callback

```
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
  NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
```

## Start the operation

```
[[APIClient sharedInstance] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
// APIClient is a singleton class for AFHTTPClient subclass
```

Comment: This worked perfect! For those of us not using a singleton as Nur does, you can just call [operation start]; after you set the uploadProgressBlock

Comment: Almost worked, but responseObject returns `NSData` instead of a `NSDictionary` or something. How would I fix this?

Comment: @yoeriboven Did you try to NSLog(%@,responseObject); ? If it's data, it's possible that it is an NSString. Then you can parse JSON into NSDictionary.

Comment: I already fixed it. Had to use `NSJSONSerialization`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a way of doing this after looking around in NSURLConnection. It means adding the following code inside of the FBRequest.h and FBRequest.m files to create a new delegate.

At the bottom of the FBRequest.m file there are all of the methods for NSURLConnectionDelegate. Add this code here:

```
- (void)connection:connection
   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    float percentComplete = ((float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:uploadPercentComplete:)])
    {
        [_delegate request:self uploadPercentComplete:percentComplete];
    }
}
```

Now put this in the FBRequest.h class to create a new FBRequest delegate:

```
/**
 * Called a data packet is sent
 *
 * The result object is a float of the percent of data sent
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request uploadPercentComplete:(float)per;
```

This goes at the bottom of the FBRequest.h file after:

```
@protocol FBRequestDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
```

Now all you have to do is call this new delegate anywhere in your code like you would any other FBRequest delegate and it will give you a float from 0.0 to 1.0 (0% to 100%).

Strange that the Facebook API doesn't have this (along with upload cancel which I found out how to do here [How to cancel a video upload in progress using the Facebook iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080581/how-to-cancel-a-video-upload-in-progress-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk)) as it's not that tricky.

Enjoy!

Comment: This does not work with the current version (3.1.1). I guess they refactored quite a bit.

Comment: Haven't checked out Facebook's new framework that they released just before iOS 6, but this code used to work for the framework before that.

Comment: Any idea how to update this to the latest SDK 3.1? I tried this but it's not working as there is no _delegate... thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't looked at Fb SDK 3.x yet. If I do I'll post an update.