# How to cancel a video upload in progress using the Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, nsurlconnection

I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK to post videos from my app to the user's facebook.

I'm trying to allow the user to cancel the upload after the upload has started.

These are the methods that starts the upload:

```
- (void)startUpload
{   
    NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
}

- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSString *filePath = [videoNSURL path];

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   videoTitle, @"title",
                                   videoDescription, @"description",
                                   nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
}
```

I cannot find any methods inside `Facebook.h` that comes with the Facebook iOS SDK that allows me to cancel the upload.

Even if I do a `[facebook release]`, it will still not cancel the FBSession which is trying to upload the video. Which means I'll get a `exc_bad_access` when the upload is complete when FBSession tries to inform the `facebook` object that the upload is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following methods:

**FBRequest**

```
(void) cancel {
   [_connection cancel];
   [_connection release], _connection = nil;
}
```

**Facebook**

```
(void)cancelPendingRequest {
  [_request cancel];
  [_request release], _request = nil;
}
```

`cancelPendingRequest` will allow me to cancel a video upload in progress.