# IOS Facebook SDK how to use UIProgressView when uploading a photo

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to show the progress of een photo upload with facebook. The upload is working correctly. But i dont know how to show the progress.

The current code for uploading is this:

```
- (IBAction)delenFacebook:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"share image");
  UIImage *img = _postImage.image;

  // if it is available to us, we will post using the native dialog
  BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                                initialText:nil
                                                                      image:img
                                                                        url:nil
                                                                    handler:nil];
  if (!displayedNativeDialog) {
    [self performPublishAction:^{

        [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:img
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   [self showAlert:@"Photo Post" result:result error:error];

                               }];


    }];
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally you would do that over delegates. I think the FBRequestConnection internally will use the NSURLConnection, which has got the NSURLConnectionDelegate. This delegate has a method called didSendBodyData. Perhaps you can add this to the class and then receive the delegate?

Comment: Just in this moment I found that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938430/how-can-i-check-the-progress-of-my-facebook-ios-upload

Dont know if it is still like that, but seems that it worked like that before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cant edite the 3.1 facebook framework. It is in form of static library. So i cant edit the FBRequest.m.

Comment: As I see it seems that its not possible anymore. Did not found a solution until now...Upvoted it, probably someone else can help you.

Comment: Did not found a solution yet. Hopefully someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this on the latest SDK 3.1? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. I did not found a solution for this. Except that you can download 3.1 framework from github and use the generator to build the framework. You can modify the code before you generate the files. I did not get to work for me. But that is what i found. I used a different solution.